# Decomposing maps on a product space (category theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have a pair of maps $f: A \to B$ and $g : X \to Y$ then we can define a map $(f\times g): A \times X \to B\times Y$.  It doesn't seem we can decompose all maps from $A\times X$ to $B\times Y$, take for example the SWAP map where SWAP $\circ \langle s,t\rangle = \langle t,s\rangle$.
But my intuition is that if $A\cong B$ and $X\cong Y$ then this is possible; or perhaps if $A=B$ and $X=Y$ then this is possible; that is, if $F: A\times B \to A\times B$ can we write $F = f\times g$ with $f:A\to A$ and $g:B\to B$. And in the isomorphic case?  The general case?

Comment: Why don’t you think this through in some simple example?

Comment: Well I don't think it's true in general.  But is it true for $F: A\times B \to A\times B$.  I've been thinking about this for about 2 days, it would be useful for me proving another more difficult result.

Comment: @KevinArlin I'm inclined to think it is NOT true even in the case when $F: A\times B \to A\times B$ but my intuition might be wrong (as it often is).  
The example that comes to mind is something like $F(x,y) = \langle x + y, y\rangle$.  If I could decompose the map then it's not clear how the first coordinate "knows" to add $y$.  Is this correct?

Comment: But perhaps we can impose enough assumptions on $F$ until it is true.

Comment: I removed the category theory tag. This is elementary set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in very simple situations this breaks down. Consider $A=B=X=Y=\{0,1\}$, and let $$f: A\times B\rightarrow X\times Y:\begin{cases}
(0,0)\mapsto (0,1)\\
(0,1)\mapsto (1,1)\\
(1,1)\mapsto (1,0)\\
(1,0)\mapsto (0,0).
\end{cases}$$

Think about going around the vertices of a square. This $f$ cannot be written as a product of functions (this is a good exercise).

More generally, note that if $g=h_1\times h_2$, then altering one coordinate of the input to $g$ can't affect the *other* coordinate of the output. So any time we have "coordinate mixing," as in the $f$ above, we can't be looking at a product of functions.